# C++ BINGO loop bool logic

Tags: c++

I need to create a loop to generate a random number 1-75 and output BINGO based on the number, and complete only whenever all the letters are output.

have not been able to come up with a loop

```
/*
Section 1 : Generate a random number from 1 to 75.
Section 2 : If the number is between 1 to 15, attach B and output the number.
Section 3 : If the number is between 16 to 30, attach I and output the number.
Section 4 : If the number is between 31 to 45, attach N and output the number.
Section 5 : If the number is between 46 to 60, attach G and output the number.
Section 6 : If the number is between 61 to 75, attach O and output the number.
Section 7 : Repeat Sec 1 through 6 until the program generates all B I N G O.
*/
#include<iostream>
#include<ctime>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int B1;
    bool B = false, I = false, N = false, G = false, O = false, bingo = false;
    srand(time(NULL)); // This line set the random number seed.
    int num = (rand() % 75) + 1;
    if (num <= 15)
    {
        cout << "B-" << num << endl;
        B = true;
    }
    else if (num <= 30)
    {
        cout << "I-" << num << endl;
        I = true;
    }
    else if (num <= 45)
    {
        cout << "N-" << num << endl;
        N = true;
    }
    else if (num <= 60)
    {
        cout << "G-" << num << endl;
        G = true;
    }
    else if (num <= 75)
    {
        cout << "O-" << num << endl;
        O = true;
    }
    return 0;
} // main
```

I am not sure where to go or how to proceed in creating the loop. This is as far as I have gotten.

Comment: You will need to generate a bingo card to check against before you can figure out if there's a winner for that card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding, you want to continue the loop till you fill all the letters of BINGO, so I have added a while loop with that condition. It stops when all the letters are found.

```
Section 1 : Generate a random number from 1 to 75. 
Section 2 : If the number is between 1 to 15, attach B and output the number.
Section 3 : If the number is between 16 to 30, attach I and output the number. 
Section 4 : If the number is between 31 to 45, attach N and output the number. 
Section 5 : If the number is between 46 to 60, attach G and output the number. 
Section 6 : If the number is between 61 to 75, attach O and output the number. 
Section 7 : Repeat Sec 1 through 6 until the program generates all B I N G O. */ 
#include<iostream>
#include<ctime>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  int B1;
  bool B = false, I = false, N = false, G = false, O = false, bingo = false;
  srand(time(NULL)); // This line set the random number seed.
  while (!(B && I && N && G && O)) {
    int num = (rand() % 75) + 1;
    if(num <= 15) {
      cout << "B-" << num << endl; 
      B = true; 
    } else if (num <= 30) {
      cout << "I-" << num << endl; 
      I = true; 
    } else if (num <= 45) { 
      cout << "N-" << num << endl; 
      N = true; 
    } else if (num <= 60) { 
      cout << "G-" << num << endl; 
      G = true; 
    } else if (num <= 75) { 
      cout << "O-" << num << endl; 
      O = true; 
    }
  }
  return 0; 
} // main
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `while` loop with your flag `bingo`. At the end of loop do check if we got all the 
Letters.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<ctime>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
int main()
{
    int B1;
    bool B = false, I = false, N = false, G = false, O = false, bingo = false;
    srand(time(NULL)); // This line set the random number seed.

    while (!bingo)
    {

        int num = (rand() % 75) + 1;
        if (num <= 15)
        {
            cout << "B-" << num << endl;
            B = true;
        }
        else if (num <= 30)
        {
            cout << "I-" << num << endl;
            I = true;
        }
        else if (num <= 45)
        {
            cout << "N-" << num << endl;
            N = true;
        }
        else if (num <= 60)
        {
            cout << "G-" << num << endl;
            G = true;
        }
        else if (num <= 75)
        {
            cout << "O-" << num << endl;
            O = true;
        }

        bingo= B && I && N && G && O;
    }
    return 0;
} // main
```